# Laravel Syntax for nested foreach with where condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Is there any laravel standard or way to achieve this in laravel 5 or greater Thank you in advance

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";`

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);


    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['category']."[";
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM subCategories where category_id = ".$row['id']." limit 4";
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
        if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo $row2['name']." ; ";
            }
        }
        echo " ]</br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with [@Muhammad Sumon Molla Selim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41922916/3918473) in defining `Eloquent` models. But when you query in the way he describes you'd face [N+1 issue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). You can `Eager load` to solve it. Just do it like this.

```
$categories = Category::with('subcategories')->get();
```

Then you could loop like this

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    foreach ($category->subcategories as $subCategory) {
        echo $subcategory;
    }
}
```

Comment: can i apply where limit directly or use if condition?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. You can use Laravel's `Eloquent ORM` and `Model` to achieve this easily.

First, you have to create two models and define the relationship between them. First the `Category` model:

```
<?php // Category.php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class);
    }
}
```

Then the `SubCategory` model:

```
<?php // SubCategory.php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SubCategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'subCategories';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

After that, it's as easy as below to get categories and the subcategories under a category:

```
<?php
// get all categories
$categories = Category::all();

// get subcategories for each category
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    $subCategories = $category->subcategories();
    foreach($subCategories as $subCategory) 
    {
        echo $subCategory;
    }
}
```